# Custom ui-bootstrap-custom-0.12.1 for popover on hover instead of click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I am not supposed to use popover.js, however I can use **ui-bootstrap-custom-01.12.1.js**.

The question was how I can get the directive to work with hover on the html content provided. One example is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6ceUmS?p=preview) but its on click want to make that popover on hover instead of click.

I want to make custom popover directive on below html on bind object patient which has patient details. I want the popover to be on hover of div element with bind object on `patient.personName`

```
<a class='bold cursor-pointer hyperlink patient-name first-level-child' bo-href='patient.link'>
    <div class = "patient-name handle-long-text" bo-bind = 'patient.personName'></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above example in plunker just change the below code instead of click put mouseenter that will solve my problem.

```
  .directive('iantooltip', [ '$iantooltip', function ($iantooltip) {
    return $iantooltip('iantooltip', 'iantooltip', 'mouseenter');
  }]);
```